# What electric starter(s) are compatible with the RCGF 120cc engine?

Tags: electronics, engine

I plan on flying the RCGF 120cc engine, however, I noticed the owner's [manual](https://www.modelarstvoimi.sk/subory/manual-rcgf-120cc-twin-5583060b24f5c.pdf) does not recommend any sort of electric starter and I have been having trouble finding one compatible with it.